# FSEvents file flags are set regardless of event stream creation options

Tags: macos, cocoa, filesystems, osx-lion, fsevents

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/FSEvents_h/index.html), in the callback to `FSEvents`,

```
/* These flags are only set if you specified the FileEvents */
/*   flags when creating the stream. */
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated = 0x00000100, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved = 0x00000200, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemInodeMetaMod = 0x00000400, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed = 0x00000800, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified = 0x00001000, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod = 0x00002000, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner = 0x00004000, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod = 0x00008000, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsFile = 0x00010000, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir = 0x00020000, 
kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink = 0x00040000
```

However, I triple checked that the `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents` flag is not being set when calling

```
FSEventStreamRef FSEventStreamCreate( 
    CFAllocatorRef allocator, 
    FSEventStreamCallback callback, 
    FSEventStreamContext *context, 
    CFArrayRef pathsToWatch, 
    FSEventStreamEventId sinceWhen, 
    CFTimeInterval latency, 
    FSEventStreamCreateFlags flags);
```

But no matter what I do, the `kFSEventStreamEventFlagItem*` flags are still being set when the events are passed to me from the `FSEvents` API. I suspect this is a bug, but I'm not quite sure. I'm using OS X Lion 10.7.2

Sample code can be found here. http://stuconnolly.com/downloads/scevents/

**EDIT**

The question is:
Has anyone else experienced the same results?
Is this a behavior I can rely on to check for the file event flags?

Comment: oops, added the question. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Seeing the same thing.  OS 10.8.2 here.  It definitely isn't behaving the way the documentation suggests.

Comment: In my case, I am testing for both `kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated` and `kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsFile`. When I create a new file in the watched directory, the callback is called but these flags aren't set!!

Answer (score 0):

In fact,these flags are set normally although the flag looks wrong.

For example,you got a flag 133120.That is 0x20800.
So,you should notice "kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed = 0x00000800"
and "kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir = 0x00020000".

That is to say, kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed & kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir are what you want.